# Apple Push Service certificate is not trusted

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, apple-m1

I have recently created an Apple Push Service certificate on my M1 mac mini. In the Keychain, it says the certificate is not trusted.

[image]

I have installed the Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate as mentioned in [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662300)

Also installed the following Intermediate Certificates from Apple

[image]

Still, the Push Service certificate shows it's not trusted. Meanwhile, new development and distribution certificates created are marked as "This certificate is valid". Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this issue?

Comment: Why does it even matter? Does it affect your ability to fire notifications from macOS?

Comment: at bottom of link  https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/add  where it says `Intermediate Certificates` click on matching link to download then once downloaded click again to install

Answer (score 191, accepted):

I have installed the G3, G4, and G5 certificates from the Apple certificate authority and that solved my problem

https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

[image]

Edit: G4 Certificate is key for solving the issue.

Comment: This is not intuitive at all .. I tested my exported cert and key via the existing Twilio services and got pushes with production and dev, but the cert in my local Mac Keychain said "not trusted" ..?  A few beads of sweat later, with a few downloads via the above link, and the cert says valid!  This causes serious confusion.. thanks a ton

Comment: Just to clarify it doesn't seem like there is any impact right? Even though the local machine says the certificate isn't trusted your services communicating with APNs using the certificate still performed normally?

Comment: Thanks man. Saved many hours. for me G4 was enough to install.

Comment: This worked for me too. The entire process is so opaque, it almost feels like intentional.

Comment: It happened to me from April 13th 2022, I requested support and they asked me about the browser which I used (...) and other thinks unrelated to this issue which was only due to their responsibility, thanks.

Comment: G5 enough for me

Comment: @whyoz You got the Exported Certification & Key to work with Twilio? I need help with that. Can't get the Notifications to work despite following all the steps from here https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/ios/push-notifications-ios

Answer (score 77):

Just a more specific answer from [Guru's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216752/7587102):

Go to the info panel of your untrusted certificate and you'll see the issuer's info, like this:
[image]

This indicates the issuer is a Worldwide Developer Relations G4 (for now).

Then go to https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ and pick that certificate and install it.

Comment: Good Explanation!!

Comment: By far more accurate than @Guru's answer

Comment: I was confused what todo, so adding it many be that will also help some else, "When you download and drag and drop it it will start showing it as valid."

Comment: This is great answer, although doesn't still explain why do I need to go download smth external.