# Voip Push not Working Production/Development

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, keychain, pushkit

Hi I have successfully integrated Push Kit and call Kit and was working earlier with no code change in recent times, Voip Certs got expired and i created new using developer.apple.com

**Voip Push aren't received in the App** and after creating the certificate it shows in the keychain as below:

[image]

Thing i have verified:

1. I am sure the bundle Id used to create the certicate is valid and matching with the App
2. No Aggreements to Accept in developer.apple.com
3. Valid Developer account subscription
4. Correct Push kit and call kit integration
5. Getting a valid token from Push registery

Tried creating PEM and using that to send notification i get error as "DeviceTokenNotForTopic" using a software of macOS to test Voip.

Update 1:
Fixed trust issue with reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216752/8030868

Can Someone please help what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was apps_topic mismatch in certificate .voip was there but while using external apps it was just bundle id so, solution was BundleID+.voip